# How to show only untracked sub-repos (not files) in git?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-status, git-ls-files

How do I show only untracked subdirectories that are git repos?  Do I use `git diff`, `git status`, or `git ls`?  What options do I use?

The closest thing I could find is:
`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M`
but that shows modified, not untracked.  And it shows files.

I'm looking for something like:

```sh
$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/my-dir
$ touch my-file
$ git add my-file
$ git commit -m 'init'
[master (root-commit) 3f18576] init
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 my-file
$ echo changed >> my-file
$ mkdir sub-repo
$ cd sub-repo
$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/my-dir/sub-repo/.git/
$ touch my-file-sub-repo
$ cd ..
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   my-file

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    sub-repo/

$ git # diff? What options?
my-dir
```

(Related: I don't know how git is treating these "sub-repos" but would like to understand.  Maybe git is considering them as git submodules, even though I never explicitly ran any git submodule commands?)

Comment: Git knows nothing about "directories" so there is no such thing as a tracked or untracked directory. Git doesn't track directories. Git doesn't store directories. A commit doesn't contain directories. Git deals in commits. Commits contain files. So Git tracks _files_. So can you express the question in terms that make sense for Git? What do you really want to know?

Comment: if a 'untracked' directory has 'untracked' files, git will show them with status. it can also show a  list of all 'tracked' files, so you can script around it to look for 'untracked' directories.

Comment: Thanks @matt .   Aha.  I realized that the directories I'm referring to contain repos themselves.  I've updated my question to reflect that.  They are not submodules.  I'm not sure how git treats "sub-repositories".  I did some searching but came up empty.

Comment: "They are not submodules". I don't believe that. You cannot put a folder containing a _.git_ folder inside _another_ folder containing a _.git_ folder except as a submodule. It would be incoherent otherwise.

Comment: @matt I never explicitly ran any `git submodule` commands to add a submodule, and running `git submodule` alone shows no existing submodules.  As indicated in my example, all I did was `git init` in a subdirectory.  I'm not really familiar with submodules, so I may be missing something.  If you run my commands above, do you get any submodules?

Comment: The point is that if you put a git folder inside a git folder and you _don't_ make submodules, you've got an incoherent situation. Basically I'm saying do _not_ do what you're doing in the first place.

Comment: Ah, that helps @matt.  What do you mean by "incoherent situation"?

Comment: Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/73725600/341994

Comment: Wow, that answer is exactly what I'm looking for -- thanks @matt !   ⭐️

Answer (score 1):

hmm. Okay, from the rewrite it seems what you want is the nested work trees or repositories that aren't tracked?

```
(
echo .git
git ls-files -s | sed -n '/^16/s,[^\t]*.,,p'
find -mindepth 1 -type d \( \
    \( -exec test -d {}/objects -a -d {}/refs -a -f {}/HEAD \; -prune -printf %P\\n \) \
 -o \( -exec test -e {}/.git \; -prune -printf %P\\n \) \)
) | sort | uniq -u
```

====

but the original question, showing all directories containing no tracked files, is also interesting, so here's what I had for that:

Git's flexible, arguably (though I'd disagree strongly) flexible to a fault, about where repositories and their work trees can reside, to the point where it's possible for a trolling guru to make it impossible to tell, but if we rule out such hopefully-playful malice it's down in fiveliner range.

All directories that contain files tracked in the current checkout anywhere underneath:

```
git ls-files \*/* \
| awk '{while(sub(/\/[^/]*$/,""))if(!seen[$0]++)print;else break}'
```

All directories that *could* contain tracked files:

```
find -mindepth 1 -type d \( \
      \( -exec test -d {}/objects -a -d {}/refs -a -f {}/HEAD \; -prune \) \
   -o \( -exec test -e {}/.git \; -prune -printf %P\\n \) \
   -o -printf %P\\n \)
```

And then just look for un-duplicated entries:

```
( git ls-files \*/* \
  | awk '{while(sub(/\/[^/]*$/,""))if(!seen[$0]++)print;else break}'

  find -mindepth 1 -type d \( \
      \( -exec test -d {}/objects -a -d {}/refs -a -f {}/HEAD \; -prune \) \
   -o \( -exec test -e {}/.git \; -prune -printf %P\\n \) \
   -o -printf %P\\n \)
) | sort | uniq -u
```

====