# How to remove unwanted, inadvertent git submodules in new repositories?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-bash, git-submodules

I am trying to add a new repository simple-form but every time I do I end up with all of the other repositories I have locally as submodules (the blue folder with white arrow that I can't delete on GitHub) in that repository.

I have a main folder called GitHub locally that isn't supposed to be a repository with all of my repositories in it in their own folders.
There are no .gitmodules that I was able to find and none of the other past repositories have that same issue.

When I search on Git Bash, only the folders that are supposed to be there show up. I have tried:

```sh
rm .gitmodules
git submodule deinit
git submodule deinit --all
git config --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp path
git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp path | awk '{print $2}'
```

and more and I keep getting `No such file or directory`.

I did lastly try
`git submodule--helper list`
on both the simple-form repository with all of the unwanted blue folders with white arrows and the GitHub folder with all the separate repositories, and I do get a list of all of them. But when I try
`git rm <path-to-submodule>`
I get
`fatal: pathspec 'eyes' did not match any files`
even when I use the path stated in that list (it just has the name of the repository folder honestly but that is supposed to be the path)

I am not really sure what to do now. I don't want to delete all of my repositories and I have a feeling that it has something to do with that main GitHub folder, I will admit I may have accidentally made that folder I keep everything in into a repository. The GitHub folder did have remote url that matches the folder called simple-form that I am trying to fix. I remove it using the `git remote remove origin` command and nothing pops up when I type `git remote -v`, but it keeps coming back every time I delete and redo the entire simple-form folder (with new names every time).

I can't create more repositories because of this issue. How do I undo these submodules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary

Remove any *unwanted* `.git` entities.  Make sure they're really *unwanted* first.  Consider *moving* them somewhere else (outside of each working tree) if they have useful data.

## Long: The cause of submodules

You *get* a submodule whenever you try to *put a Git repository inside a Git commit*.

That's really all it is, but to understand this—why this is, and what it all means—you have to understand a *Git repository*, and if one reads the Git questions on StackOverflow, it's quite clear that many people do not understand what a Git repository really is.  I for one find this unsurprising, given that so many Git tutorials seem to start out saying something like "Git is complicated, we'll demystify it for you: start with these magic arbitrary commands, and ..."—well, this stuff doesn't demystify anything at all.  **Git *is* complicated, but if we view it from a high level, it's not that bad:  Git is all about *commits*.**

Now, this is a bit like viewing the Earth from a high level: say, from the Moon: You're going to miss a lot of detail.  But you can immediately tell a lot from this!  Well, you can if you know what a *commit* is.

[image: NASA, Public domain, via Wikimedia Commons]

#### Commits

A *commit*, in Git:

- Is numbered: each commit gets a *unique* ID.  Git calls this universally unique ID (UUID) a *hash ID*, or more formally an *object ID*.  It looks random and it's very large.  Here are a few sample hash IDs, written in tiny characters to make them fit better: [<sub><sup>`e188ec3a735ae52a0d0d3c22f9df6b29fa613b1e`</sup></sub>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e188ec3a735ae52a0d0d3c22f9df6b29fa613b1e), [<sub><sup>`f20b9c36d034fe37715d18ef67183cf5544227a7`</sup></sub>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f20b9c36d034fe37715d18ef67183cf5544227a7).

  Git rather magically assigns every *new* commit a *new* hash ID, never used before, never to be used again.  Each Git implementation, working in any one Git repository, somehow does this without ever talking with any other Git implementation working with any *other* repository.  This seems impossible,<sup>1</sup> and yet it works in practice.
- Is read-only: once you make a commit, you cannot change it.  Not even *Git* can change it.  This is required to make the numbering scheme work.
- Contains a *full snapshot of every file*, as a sort of permanent archive, plus some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.

We won't go into all the details here since we're just concerned with a repository as a collection of commits, but I will mention that the *full snapshot* here means that each commit does in fact store every file.  To keep the repository *size* under control, Git uses another bit of magic here, where each file's *content* is *de-duplicated*.  The de-duplication means that when two commits store mostly the *same* files—and most commits  mostly store the same files over and over again, after all—those two commits literally *share* the duplicate files.  This is enabled by the read-only-ness of those files.  It's safe for Git to notice that, hey, the contents of this `README.md` file exactly match the contents of a previous `README.txt` file, so let's just *re-use* the old content!  (Note that the file's *name* is irrelevant here.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It seems impossible because it *is* impossible.  It will someday stop working.  The sheer size of the hash ID space puts that day off so long that—we hope—we'll all be dead and gone, and maybe even the universe won't exist any more, before it happens.  We're depending on luck to some extent, but it's pretty solid luck mathematically.

---

#### A repository is primarily a collection of commits

A Git *repository*, then, consists mostly of a big database of all the commit *objects*.  Every commit ever made—well, made *for this particular repository*, as cloned from some earlier clone and updated by obtaining *new* commits from other clones—goes into this database.  Git looks up these commits by their big ugly hash ID commit-numbers.  You give Git a commit number, and Git can fish out the commit: the snapshot, plus the metadata.

We (humans) are very bad at commit numbers, so we don't actually use those numbers *directly* most of the time.  We use branch names, tag names, and all kinds of other names.  These names also go into a (second, separate) database, where they store the numbers.  So they're just ways of getting the numbers without having to memorize random-looking hash IDs.  So we run, e.g., `git switch main`, and Git looks up `main` and comes up with the latest commit hash ID and plucks out the commit *from* the commits-and-other-objects database and now we, or at least Git, have the snapshot-and-metadata.

And that's what a repository is, at its core.  **A Git repository consists of the two databases: names that find hash IDs, and commit-and-other-objects as found by hash IDs.**  Each repository has *its own* (semi-private) *names*, but literally *shares* the commits, by their universally unique hash ID numbers, with other clones.  **This is what `git fetch` and `git push` are about: you get (fetch) and send (push) *commits* to update your databases.**

#### You can't work directly on a commit, so you get a working tree

Each commit has its two parts: metadata and full snapshot.  These two parts are both *frozen for all time*, so that the magic commit numbering scheme works.  But we can't get any *work* done with a block of files all frozen into some icy mass.  We have to thaw the files out and put them somewhere *useful*, in ordinary computer-file format.  The special compressed-and-de-duplicated format that commits keep is no good for getting work done.

In order for you to get work done, then, a *normal* repository comes with one additional area, which Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  This is quite simply the place where you get work done.

Whenever you *clone* a repository, Git:

- creates a new, empty repository (no names, no commits, nothing in the working tree);
- *fetches* all the commits and other objects from some *other* Git repository;
- creates *one new branch name* in your clone, because working with Git without using branch names is possible but would make you miserable; and
- *checks out* that one branch, thus *filling in* your working area.

I emphasized *normal repository* above because Git has a special (abnormal?) flavor of repository, the so-called *bare* repository, that deliberately omits the working tree.  By omitting this work area, Git can be sure that nobody will attempt to get any work done in this kind of repository.  That makes the repository *always capable of receiving push operations*.  Any Git repository can *sometimes* receive push operations, but if there's ongoing work, the incoming push could mess with it.  By not providing a work area, a *bare* repository enables incoming pushes always.  **Bare repositories are basically only for server use and you generally should avoid them.**  (They do have a few rare, special-case uses for non-server work, though.)

#### The concrete implementation of a repository

Any actual Git repository has to be realized (i.e., implemented) on a computer.  As our computers like to store stuff in files that are stored in folders, Git stores its databases inside files inside folders.  The *folder name* for a normal (non-bare) Git repository is always `.git`.  This folder is normally *hidden:* the very name `.git` implies "hidden" on Linux and macOS systems, and on Windows, Git uses the Windows "hide this folder" flag to hide it.  So you normally don't *see* this `.git` folder—but it's there.

What's inside the `.git` folder is Git's business, but you're free to look, if you like.  Just don't *depend on* what you find, since Git might change in the future (it has changed in the past).  In general, today, you'll find one file named `HEAD`, and at least two sub-folders, one named `objects` and one named `refs`.  These two sub-folders store the commit-and-other-objects database and the names database (well, sometimes...) respectively.  The special file `HEAD` keeps track of which *branch name* is the *current branch name* (and has some other tricks, but we won't cover those here).

#### More about your working tree

**You now know what a repository is, and what one looks like, at least from a high-level view.**  The actual implementation is this hidden `.git` folder.  But what about your working tree?

Your *working tree* is initially *empty* when you run `git clone`, but by the time `git clone` finishes, `git clone` has run `git switch` or `git checkout` and *filled in* your working tree.  Your working tree now contains *all the files from the commit you've selected to check out*.

In other words, Git takes the snapshot *for* the current commit, and un-archives / thaws-out all the frozen files, making usable copies of them.  Those usable copies go into your working tree.

You can also build a working tree yourself by making an empty folder, entering it (however you do that on your computer), and filling it with various files and—at some point, before or after creating files—running `git init`.  Git will *create* the hidden `.git` folder at this point.

**In all of these cases, the hidden `.git` folder is at the top level of your working tree.**  That is, if you use whatever command(s) you have to see all files and folders, including hidden ones, and run this from the *top level* of your working tree, you'll see the hidden `.git` directory that contains the implementation of the repository.

**What this means is simple: the repository is *inside the working tree*.  This should seem kind of weird and upside down to you, because it *is* kind of weird and upside down.**  But it's actually sort of traditional on Unix-like systems.  It avoids needing to put the repository databases in a separate, parallel location, apart from the working tree—but, as it turns out, this leads directly to our submodule problem.

#### A Git commit is not allowed to contain a Git repository

To keep the hidden `.git` folder from going into some *commit*, Git *forbids you from adding the `.git` folder*.  If you try it, Git just silently ignores the attempt:

```
$ git add .git
```

Nothing happens: no error messages, nothing at all.  There's no `.git` added.  Git just doesn't do anything.

But: what happens if you make a new directory and put a repository *into* that new directory?  Let's try it:

```
$ mkdir t
$ cd t 
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo test embedded repository > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) e4c4fd8] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git add -v t/.git
```

Nothing happens at this point: Git ignores the attempt to add `t/.git` entirely.  But what if we add `t`, the *folder that contains the hidden `.git` folder* plus—of course—the working-tree files, which in this case consist just of the one `README` file?  Now something interesting happens:

```
$ git add -v t
add 't/'
warning: adding embedded git repository: t
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> t
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached t
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

**Pay attention to these hint lines!**  They tell us that I've just accidentally added a submodule, and that I've done it wrong—that I should have used `git submodule add`, not `git add`.

This *is* a mistake and I should immediately correct it, as the hint suggests, using `git rm --cached t`.  (The hint fails to mention that I need `-f` as well.)  Since this is a real repository in which I've made this test submodule, I will do that now, but I'll start with `git submodule status`, which shows the broken submodule setup I made:

```
$ git submodule status
fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 't'
$ git rm --cached t
error: the following file has staged content different from both the
file and the HEAD:
    t
(use -f to force removal)
$ git rm -f --cached t
rm 't'
```

Here you can see the process by which I undid this accidental submodule.

#### Correct use of submodules

To add a submodule *correctly*, **should I wish to do so**, I would have to follow the `hint:` advice lines and run `git submodule add`.  When using `git submodule add`, you *must provide a URL*.  This URL is the one that Git will later use to `git clone` the submodule.

Remember, a submodule is a *second, separate Git repository*.  If someone later clones my main repository, my main repository needs to list the *URL* for the *second* (submodule) repository.  This way *they* can clone the submodule too.

The URL I put in, when I run `git submodule add`, should be the URL at which the submodule will be, or already is, clone-able.  My *superproject*—i.e., my initial repository, where I have the files I've been working on before I started all this submodule stuff—will contain commits that contain a file named `.gitmodules` that will store this URL.  It will also contain, in these new commits, instructions for *checking out* the desired commit *in* the submodule.  Using `git submodule add` will set all this up for me.

We'll also want to use `git submodule absorbgitdirs`.  The purpose of this is to move the hidden `.git` folder out of the submodule's top level working tree.  That is, `t/.git` is currently a hidden Git repository *folder*.  Storing it here in `t/` is actually a problem, so `git submodule absorbgitdirs` will move the *submodule* repository inside the `.git` that holds the *superproject* repository.  It will then replace the `.git` that was in `t/.git` with a *file* named `t/.git`, that tells Git where to find the "absorbed" submodule.

You presumably *don't* want a submodule here though, so let's not get any further into this particular topic.  Just remember that the Git repository—normally a hidden *folder* named `.git`—is sometimes replaced by a hidden *file* named `.git`.

#### When you don't want a submodule, don't have a Git repository

To avoid *creating* a submodule, we must make sure that our sub-directory (`t/` or whatever) holds no hidden `.git`.  As we just saw, this could be either a `.git` folder, or a `.git` file.  Either one acts as a sort of poison.  **A Git commit is not allowed to contain a Git repository.**  We said this earlier (as a section header) but it bears repeating.<sup>2</sup>  Since a commit can't contain `.git`, we must make sure that there are no other `.git` entities in our working tree.

**We do have to leave the top level `.git` alone.**  Remember that the `.git` folder *contains the actual Git repository*, which has all the commits and other objects, plus all the names.  Removing a `.git` folder *destroys the repository*.  But the `.git` folder itself is *separate from* the working tree.  It's merely *contained within* the working tree.

When we have a Git repository within the working tree of some other Git repository—like the `t/.git` I made above—*that* is what causes our problem.  So we "fix" this by getting rid of this `.git`.

**Removing the `.git` entity means there's no longer a repository here.**  So if we remove `t/.git` entirely, there's no longer a *repository*.  There are only the remaining working-tree `t/*` files (in my case, `t/README`).  **Of course, removing the `.git` entity removes the repository.**  That is, you've removed all the commits and the names database, plus any ancillary files Git needs to use `t/` *as* a Git repository.  **If that's your goal, and you don't care about those old commits, that's exactly what you want to do.**

If you want to *keep* the other *repository*, consider either cloning your clone—though remember that when you do this, you get only *one branch* in your new clone—or simply *moving* (renaming) the hidden `.git` folder so that it's no longer in that working tree.  For instance, if the `t/.git` repository itself had precious data, I could:

```
mkdir ../keep
mv t/.git ../keep/.git
```

and I'd there by save the *repository*, though not any of the working tree files.  Or I could do:

```
(cd t; tar cf - .) | (mkdir ../keep && cd ../keep && tar xf -)
```

which is a Unix / Linux-ish sequence to copy the entire tree—both the working tree and the `.git` folder—from `t/` to `../keep/`.  Then I could:

```
rm -rf t/.git
```

to remove the copy *in* `t/`.

How and whether to *save the other repository* is up to you.  The key is to *move it out of the subdirectory (sub-folder) of the working tree of the main repository you wish to use*.  That way no *sub*-folder (or sub-file) is named `.git` and Git won't administratively change an "add all the files in here" into a "create submodule" operation.

---

<sup>2</sup>The reason to prevent a Git repository from containing a Git repository is not just to prevent infinite recursion, but also an administrative / security thing.  This is to some extent the same as the reason that Git now has the `safe.directory` stuff in it.  There's actually a slight bug in the "Git commit cannot contain Git repository" rules, over and above the old, long-fixed bug where you used to be able to sneak one in by naming it `.GIT` or `.giT` or other mixed-case name tricks, but we won't cover this here either.

Comment: Short answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule?rq=3